# Use GET method instead of POST in dropzone

Tags: javascript, php, post, get, dropzone.js

I'm using Dropzone for the file image uploading facility in my website. What I want to do is just use GET method instead of POST in the dropzone.js file.

The default value is "post". So, when I changed it to "get" it doesn't work (Not uploading files). Is there anything more I should do more than changing POST to GET ?

Here is what I did...

```
Dropzone.autoDiscover = false;
   jQuery(document).ready(function() {

   $("div#my-awesome-dropzone").dropzone({
       maxFiles: 5,
       url: "image-uploader.php",
       method :"get"
   );

});
```

The reason I want to use GET method is I want to pass a value through the URL. Like this...

```
image-uploader.php?id=4
```

So, is there any other way of doing this ? (Passing a value to `image-uploader.php`) Or what's the way of using GET instead of POST...

Comment: You should POST the uploads (GET has a limited size). You could just add whatever GET variables you need to the request URL

Comment: I believe, You are not able todo it directly. All you need is passing data as a `GET` method to controller then `UPDATE` or `POST` it there. It will be double processing for an each image upload.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for [PHP $_REQUEST](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.request.php)